# Difference between SolrJ's ResponseParsers

Tags: java, xml, solr, solrj

**The SolrJ library offers different parsers for Solr's responses.**

Namely:

- BinaryResponseParser
- StreamingBinaryResponseParser
- NoOpResponseParser
- XMLResponseParser

**Sadly the documentation doesn't say much about them, other than:**

> SolrJ uses a binary format, rather than XML, as its default format.
>   Users of earlier Solr releases who wish to continue working with XML
>   must explicitly set the parser to the XMLResponseParser, like so:
>   `server.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());`

So it looks like the XMLResponseParser is there mainly for legacy purposes.

- What are the differences between the others parsers?
- Can I expect performance improvements by using an other parser over the XMLResponseParser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Binary Stream Parsers is meant to work directly with the Java Object Format (the binary POJO format) to make the creation of data objects as smooth as possible on the client side.

The XML parser was designed to work with the old response format where there wasn't any real alternatives (as there was no binary response format in Solr). It's a lot more work to consider all the options for an XML format than use the binary format directly.

The StreamingBinaryResponseParser does the same work as the BinaryResponseParser, but has been designed to make streaming documents (i.e. not creating a list of documents and returning that list, but instead return each document by itself without having to hold them all in memory at the same time) possible. See [SOLR-2112](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2112) for a description of the feature and why it was added.

Lastly, yes, if you're using SolrJ, use the binary response format, unless you have a very good reason for using the XML based one. If you have to ask the question, you're probably better off with the binary format.